# Some tabs in TabLayout fails to render on ICS

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, render, android-tablayout

I implemented **TabLayout** in my APP and it works fine on all test devices, except on a **samsung** test device running **ICS**. One Tab shows **map** it works fine (**first image**), but when pressing on the **next tab** containing normal data, the tab content appears corrupted (**second image**).

Surprisingly, the swiping action doesn't generate the same problem (i.e. when you are on **Tab1** and swipe left, the **2nd** tab renders properly and we see the screen correctly!). (**third image**).

One more finding was that, taking a **screen shot** from the APP from the corrupted tab, doesn't capture the curruption! The shot shows perfect view!! (**fourth image**).

I wonder if anyone faced similar issue, or have an advise.

---

XML file:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**1. First image:**

[image: First screenshoot]

**2. Second image:**

[image]

**3. Third image:**

[image]

**4. Fourth image:**

[image]